# cbind a list of dataframe and to a vector of list

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

let say I have a nested list with data.frame called list_df_A which have the following structure:

```
$ :'data.frame':      1 obs. of 3 variables:
  ..$ a             :chr a1
  ..$ b             :chr b1
  ..$ c             :chr c1

$ :'data.frame':      3 obs. of 3 variables:
  ..$ a             :chr [1:3] a21 a22 a23
  ..$ b             :chr [1:3] b21 b22 b23
  ..$ c             :chr [1:3] c21 c22 c23

$ :'data.frame':      1 obs. of 3 variables:
  ..$ a             :chr a3
  ..$ b             :chr b3
  ..$ c             :chr c3
```

so if I rbind them into a data.table/data.frame:

```
list_df_A <- rbindlist(list_df_A)
```

list_df_A will then look like this:

```
      a     b     c
1:   a1    a2    a3
2:  a21   b21   c21
3:  a22   b22   c22
4:  a23   b23   c23
5:   a3    b3    c3
```

Now, I have another list. This list is actually the root of a json file. 
Let me call this list list_root which have the following structure:

```
chr [1:3] "type1" "type2" "type3"
```

if I make it as data.table/data.frame:

```
list_root <- as.data.table(list_root)
```

I get this table

```
       V1
1:  type1
2:  type2
3:  type3
```

**The question now comes: I know that type2 in *list_root* has 3 records in *list_df_A*. This is because each "type" refers to one dataframe in *list_df_A***

How do you tell R when it cbind the two data.table together, it will show something like this?

```
           V1       a     b     c
     1: type1      a1    a2    a3
     2: type2     a21   a21   a21
     3: type2     b22   b22   b22
     4: type2     c23   c23   c23
     5: type3      a3    b3    c3
```

In a sense, row 2,3,4 belongs to type2?

Comment: Doesn't `rbindlist` have an `idcol` argument that keys off the names of the list you pass it? For just this purpose?

Comment: ...and why do you keep referencing `cbind` if all you're doing is row-binding?

Comment: When I mention cbind I want to mention column bind. like the last dataframe. you can see the first column in the last dataframe is from list_root and the second to last column is list_df_A.

Comment: Ah. Well, then I'd just make that list you're starting with be named list and use the `idcol` in `rbindlist` and you should be set.

Comment: When you mention rbindlist using idcol, I have thought of an idea. For the list_root, i use rbindlist(list_root, use.names= TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol=TRUE). Then for list_df_A, i use  rbindlist(list_df_A, use.names= TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol=TRUE). Now both dataframe have an .id column. I can then use for example data.frame to merge them together by .id. Like merge(list_df_A, list_root, on=".id").

Comment: I cannot generate an ".id" on list_root because it is not an rbind of a list of many. Is there anyway to generate ".id"?

Comment: I don't understand exactly why you're doing anything that complicated. `names(list_df_A) <- list_root; rbindlist(list_df_A,idcol = "id")` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to rbindlist you can supply each data frame with an outside vector of ids using mapply

```
my_list <- mapply(`[<-`, my_list, 'colname', value = list_root , SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

And then, just rbind all of them.

Comment: You can set all the names of a list in one line just by doing `names(my_list) <- character_vector_of_names`. No need for `mapply`.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to this is:

We use the .id as key to merge two dataframe/datatable together.

for list_root, we first turn it into datatable format, then add a column with ".id" so we have a key:

```
list_root <- as.data.table(list_root)[, .id := seq(1, nrow(list_root),1)]
```

Next I can use rbindlist on list_df_A:

```
list_df_A <- rbindlist(list_df_A, use.names=TRUE, fill=TRUE, idcol=TRUE)
```

Now both have an common key ".id" we can then perform merge:

```
new_dt <- merge(list_root, list_df_A, on=".id")
```

And we get the required result:

```
       V1       a     b     c    .id
 1: type1      a1    a2    a3      1
 2: type2     a21   a21   a21      2
 3: type2     b22   b22   b22      2
 4: type2     c23   c23   c23      2
 5: type3      a3    b3    c3      3
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the names of your list and then use the `idcol` argument as follows:

```
names(list_df_A) <- list_root
rbindlist(list_df_A,idcol = "id")
```